# Show/Hide Post Text Item Oracle APEX

Tags: javascript, html, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a Post Text Item at the end of my text fields.

[image: Post text item at the end]

When I click on it, it shows a PopUp, that retrieves a key to insert in one of my tables. It is possible that after I close the PopUp, the Post Item disappear from the screen?

I call the popup this way:

```
      <a href="javascript:callMyPopup(836,'P831_AC_KEY_1','P831_AC_KEY','P836_AC_KEY','P836_AC_KEY_1');">

<img src="/i/list.gif" title="Select Service" width="13" height="13" alt="Popup Lov" />
</a>
<div id = "msg1" style="color:red"><strong></strong></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is "callMyPopup" ? Is this a popup to an inline dialog or a separate modal page ?

Comment: What version of apex are you on - is it really 5.1

Comment: callMyPopup is a separate modal page, aside from my original page, and yes, I'm in 5.1

Comment: I put a sample together for an inline modal dialog. If that is an option for you I can document it. Not sure how to capture the close event for a different modal page. Basically you need to listen for the close event and then hide the div or span that has this post item text (surround it with a span that has an id)

Answer (score 0):

I figure a way to trick the user. The original field is shown with a server side condition, where item IS NOT NULL. When Item IS NULL, I hide the other. It is a workaround but it works. And the user will see like the button hides.

Maybe someone can find this "solution" easy or can come with a better idea.
Thanks anyway!